# why is setdibits failing in masm assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86-64, masm

I've been working on outputting a `bitmap image` to the screen, the `bitmap` is 50 pixels by 50 pixels, but when i try to draw the bits to a `DDB` using `setdibits` it fails and then i get a black box on the screen because the `CreateCompatibleBitmap` makes a 50 by 50 pixel black `bitmap`. Does anybody know why `SetDIBits` is failing or how to fix it.

Main body of my code

```
includelib user32.lib
include externals.asm
include wincons.asm
.data
include variables.asm
include pic.asm
.code
start proc
    mov holder, rsp
    and rsp, -16
    sub rsp, 32
    call __imp_GetDesktopWindow
    mov rcx, rax
getdcfail:
    call __imp_GetDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je getdcfail
    mov screendc, rax
    mov rcx, rax
    call __imp_CreateCompatibleDC
    mov picdc, rax
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, 50
    mov r8, 50
    call __imp_CreateCompatibleBitmap
    mov rcx, picdc
    mov rdx, rax
    mov r13, rax
    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, 50
    lea r12, [pic1colorbytes]
    push r12
    lea r12, [bitmapinfo]
    push r12
    push DIB_RGB_COLORS
    call __imp_SetDIBits
    add rsp, 24
    mov rcx, picdc
    mov rdx, r13
    call __imp_SelectObject
    mov rbx, 10000000
drawscreen:
    mov rcx, screendc
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, 50
    push 50
    push picdc
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0CC0020h; srccopy is hex cc0020
    call __imp_bitblt
    add rsp, 40
    dec rbx
    cmp rbx, 0
    jne drawscreen
releasedcfail:
    mov rdx, screendc
    xor rcx, rcx
    call __imp_ReleaseDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je releasedcfail
    ;mov rcx, picdc
    ;call __imp_DeleteDC
    xor rcx, rcx
    call __imp_ExitProcess
    mov rsp, holder
    ret
start endp
end
```

externals.asm

```
extern __imp_GetDC:qword
extern __imp_ReleaseDC:qword
extern __imp_GetDesktopWindow:qword
extern __imp_ExitProcess:QWORD
extern __imp_SetDIBits:qword
extern __imp_BitBlt:qword
extern __imp_CreateDIBitmap:qword
extern __imp_DeleteObject:qword
extern __imp_DeleteDC:qword
extern __imp_CreateCompatibleBitmap:qword
extern __imp_SelectObject:qword
extern __imp_CreateCompatibleDC:qword
extern __imp_GetDesktopWindow:qword
```

wincons.asm

```
DIB_RGB_COLORS equ <0>
```

variables.asm

```
align qword
holder qword ?
screendc qword ?
picdc qword ?
```

pic.asm was a 50 by 50 dib created with photoshop, then all the hex values extracted and allocated as bytes. this is the beginning part of pic.asm, whole thing is 10061 lines long

```
align dword
pic1:
byte 042H
byte 04DH
byte 048H
byte 027H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 036H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
bitmapinfo:
byte 028H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 032H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 032H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 001H
byte 000H
byte 020H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 012H
byte 027H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 023H
byte 02EH
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 023H
byte 02EH
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
byte 000H
pic1colorbytes:
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
byte 000H
byte 0FFH
byte 0FFH
```

Comment: What does GetDIBits return? What does GetLastError return?

Comment: I assume you mean SetDIBits, SetDIBits returns 0. and GetLastError returns 00000000000036B7 otherwise known as ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND

Comment: It looks like your BITMAPINFO structure is missing the biClrUsed and biClrImportant fields.  I wouldn't trust anything to generate the correct structures as this is an in memory format, and not a well defined file format.

Comment: i looked at the documentation [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader) and the documentation matches up with what `pic.asm` exactly from after `bitmapinfo` and that's where the pointer is  so i don't think that is the problem. `biClrUsed` and `biClrImportant` fields are both 0.

Comment: Note your `BITMAPINFO` is missing the `bmiColors[1]` member (e.g. you have a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` not a `BITMAPINFO`).

Comment: i thought `pic1colorbytes` was the `bmicolors[1]` member of `bitmapinfo`. how is it different?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: code review: Windows x64 guarantees 16 byte stack alignment before a `call`.  If `start` is called in an ABI-compliant way, you don't need `and rsp, -16`, just `sub rsp, 8 + 16*n` (including any pushes).  If you did want to over-align the stack, e.g. by 32, you can use RBP to hold the old RSP, again like compilers do if you use an `alignas(32) volatile int x = 1;` or something.  So `push rbp`; `mov rbp, rsp` ; `and rsp, -32`; `sub rsp, 32*n`.  Then of course you can return with `leave` ; `ret`.

Comment: You are passing the parameters to SetDIBits and BitBlt in the wrong place. Also, you do not declare any unwind codes, which is particularly concerning since you are also doing a shrink-wrap which is more complicated to unwind than a more traditional function.

Comment: @NathanielSmith It looks like I miscounted.  Still you'd be better off using filling in the structure yourself using DWORD and WORD directives so it's more clear.

Comment: whats the correct place to pass parameters @RaymondChen

Comment: The x64 software conventions are [quite complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019). The calling conventions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).

Comment: i knew about those links I've read them multiple times and i thought i was doing things right, and im doing bitblt the same as setdibits and bitblt is working and setdibits is not

Comment: Parameters are not `push`ed. They are stored directly into the stack starting at offset 32. See the diagram in the second link. The easiest way to see the convention is to compile some C code and look at the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and how to properly pass parameters, i read "the rest are pushed onto the stack" and thought of the `push` opcode. @RaymondChen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetDIBits` was failing simply because i didn't understand calling conversion fully. I thought when it said "all other parameters are passed to the stack" i thought of the `opcode` `push`, but what it meant was setting the parameters by `mov` with an offset. so when i changed the calling conversion it outputted the `bitmap`, but in monochrome. I then learned that it was because i was using `picdc` with `createCompatibleBitmap` and i instead needed to use `screenDC` so when i fixed that it outputted properly.

Here is the fixed code, only the main body was changed everything else stayed the same.

```
includelib user32.lib
include externals.asm
include wincons.asm
.data
include variables.asm
include pic.asm
.code
start proc frame
    DB 48h
    push rbx
    .pushreg rbx
    push r13
    .pushreg r13
    push rbp
    .pushreg rbp
    sub rsp, 80
    .allocstack 80
    lea rbp, [rsp + 80]
    .setframe rbp, 80
    .endprolog
    call __imp_GetDesktopWindow
    mov rcx, rax
getdcfail:
    call __imp_GetDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je getdcfail
    mov screendc, rax
    mov rcx, rax
    call __imp_CreateCompatibleDC
    mov picdc, rax
    mov rcx, screendc
    mov rdx, 50
    mov r8, 50
    call __imp_CreateCompatibleBitmap
    mov rcx, screendc
    mov rdx, rax
    mov r13, rax
    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, 50
    lea rax, [bitmapinfo + 28h]
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], rax
    lea rax, [bitmapinfo]
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], rax
    mov eax, 0
    mov dword ptr [rsp + 30h], eax
    call __imp_SetDIBits
    mov rcx, picdc
    mov rdx, r13
    call __imp_SelectObject
    mov rbx, 10000000
drawscreen:
    mov rcx, screendc
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, 50
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], 50
    mov rax, picdc
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], rax
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 30h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 38h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 40h], 0CC0020h; srccopy is hex cc0020
    call __imp_bitblt
    dec rbx
    cmp rbx, 0
    jne drawscreen
releasedcfail:
    mov rdx, screendc
    xor rcx, rcx
    call __imp_ReleaseDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je releasedcfail
    ;mov rcx, picdc
    ;call __imp_DeleteDC
    xor rcx, rcx
    call __imp_ExitProcess
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    pop r13
    pop rbx
    ret
start endp
end
```

EDIT: I fixed a few more errors in my code pointed out by Raymond Chen

Comment: You are missing a `db 48h` before the `push rbp` to ensure that the first instruction is at least 2 bytes long. You're missing a `.pushreg rbp` directive after your `push rbp`, an `.allocstack 80` after the `sub rsp, 80`, and finally a `.setframe rbp, 80` and `.endprolog` after the `lea rbp, [rsp+80]`. Your code also fails to preserve the `rbx` register. x86-64 assembly is very complicated on Windows due to all the software conventions.